# How to assign variable value as variable name in Robot Framework for dynamically making global variables?

Tags: variables, syntax, robotframework, keyword

I want to make a Robot Framework keyword which can dynamically generate global variables. This means one of the arguments will be the name of a variable. Example of the code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    MakeVariable    name
    Log             ${name}

*** Keywords ***
MakeVariable
    [Arguments]     ${variableName}
    Set Global Variable      ${${variableName}}      My Name
```

I want this code to call the MakeVariable keyword which will make a global variable '${name}' with the value of 'My Name'. But when I run this robot file, I'll get an error:

```
No keyword with name '${${variableName}' found.
```

Can somebody help to make this keyword functional? Thanks!

Comment: That code is working when I try it

Comment: works for me as well